# LINQ query to join two sets and filter on the result set

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have two tables

```
School
ID  Name 
1   School1
2   School2

Student
ID  SchoolID IsAStudent  IsATeacher
1    1             1         0
2    1             1         0
3    2             1         0
4    2             0         1

public class School
{
 public int ID {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I have a `List<School> school= new List<School>();`

**Input:**

```
School s1 = new School() { ID =1 ,Name ="School1"};
School s2 = new School() {ID= 2, Name = "School2"};
school.Add(s1);
school.Add(s2);
```

This list contains School with Ids 1 and 2.

**Expected Output:**

I need to check if atleast of one of the Schools doesnt have a teacher.

In our example since **School1** doesnt have a teacher I should get **true** from the below funtion:

```
public bool IsTeacherNotPresentAtleastInOneSchool(List<School> school)
{
  var a = (from b in school
           join c in _studentEntity.GetAll()
           on b.ID equals c.SchoolID
           where c.IsATeacher == false
           select b).ToList();
 if(a.Count >0)
   return true;
 else
   return false;
}
```

Although the above usecase will pass ,the **a.Count** will return **3** records which causes one usecase below to fail.

.Suppose I have only one School with *School2* ,
then there would be 2 rows in **Student** table 
- one row as a student with ID 3 and 
  another as teacher with ID 4 .

Even in this situation I would get **a.Count** as 1 which is incorrect since my problem statement is "**If Atleast one School which doesnt have a teacher return true**". How do I solve this?

Comment: Edit your question to be a [mcve]. As is, it is missing the `School` class, given inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Better! A sample of `_studentEntity` is still missing though. Keep improving your post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Group `students` by `schoolId` before `join`, i tried this code for `Linq to Object`, and it's wok well:

1 - Build grouping School for students, and check if all `IsATeacher` for each `school`in `students` are `false`

```
var groupedSchool = _studentEntity.GetAll()
    .GroupBy(x => x.SchoolID)
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.All(x => !x.IsATeacher));
```

**Result for 1**:

```
SchoolID  IsDontHasTeacher
1          true
2          false
```

2 - change the existing `Query` to:

```
var a = (from b in schools
         join c in groupedSchool
         on b.ID equals c.Key 
         where c.Value == true
         select b).ToList();
return a.Count > 0;
```

I hope this help